# TypeScript Structural Typing with exception?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I will provide two examples to show where I got stuck. In the first example I have two points: one 2d, one 3d:

```
type Point2D = { x: number, y: number };
type Point3D = { x: number, y: number, z: number };

let point2D: Point2D = { x: 10, y: 10 };
let point3D: Point3D = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 20 };

point2D = point3D; // without error.
```

While in another simple example on declaring/initializing a point(2d) it shows an error:

```
type Point = { x: number, y: number };
let point: Point = { x: 0, y: 0, yy: 0 }; // Error
```

The error:

```
Type '{ x: number; y: number; yy: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Point'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'yy' does not exist in type 'Point'.
```

Can anyone teach me why the behaviour is different?

Here is my trying explanation. I'm new to TS so this is absolutely not a formal one:

In the first example, the entire init object is expected to be used(by intuition). While in the second example, it's an assignment and it's normal to expect that something surplus will be dropped in an assignment.

Comment: That's intentional. You stated that you want to have exact this type, but just after statement put something not exactly the same. Thus TS expects that this is a mistake and warns you.  ```let point: Point & {yy:0} = { x: 0, y: 0, yy: 0 }; ``` will work

Comment: Oh, that's reasonable. I think my confusion might come from something called "initialization with another type" or so.

Comment: This is called excess property checks. It is only triggered when you assign a fresh object literal to something that has an explicit type. And yes. It is an exception to structural subtyping

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: I like exceptions. How about putting it into an answer! This is informative for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `point2d = point3d` statement does not throw error is:

TypeScript [Excess Property Checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error.

TypeScript lets us pass `{ size: number; label: string; }` to something that only expected a `{ label: string; }`

For the below example:

```
type Point = { x: number, y: number };
let point: Point = { x: 0, y: 0, yy: 0 };
```

This code throws an error because the object literal has a property `yy` that the target type `Point` doesn't have.

Comment: Might I also ask you that the reason they updated the docs and I found nowhere this phrase is shown in the new version anymore? I mean this should be an important idea, why omit them in the new docs?